# Visualforce page to create both an account and a contact

Tags: visualforce

I'm looking for a way to create a very simple page where a user can create both an account and contact, only having to enter the information once. If someone can help me get started with just a page with one name field that applies to both account and contact, I should be able to figure out the rest.

I'm somewhat new to Visualforce but I am capable of making a page to create just an account or just a contact, I'm hoping I don't need to dig deep and learn how to create custom controllers to do this.

Comment: I'll be interested to see if there's a hacky solution the community provides, but AFAIK you can't create multiple types of records on the same page using strictly standard controllers and no custom code. Achieving this with a controller extension would be fairly manageable for someone with basic programming knowledge

Comment: What about using the process builder to take the information from the account to create the contact record with the same details?

Comment: That's a great idea Jenny, I'm much more comfortable with the process builder than creating visualforce pages, I can't believe I didn't think of that. If I can't get it figured out with visualforce I will definitely do that.

Answer (score 1):

Controller

```
public exampleClass{

   public Contact newCon {get;set;}

   public exampleClass(ApexPages.StandardController con){
      newCon = (Contact)con.getRecord();
   }

   public pagereference save(){
      Account a = New Account(Name = newCon.FirstName + ' ' + newCon.LastName);
      Insert a;
      newCon.AccountID = a.id;
      insert newCon;

      Pagereference pr = New PageReference('/' + a.id);
      return pr;
   }

}
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="exampleClass">

   <apex:form>

     <apex:inputField value="{!newCon.FirstName}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!newCon.LastName}"/>
     <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" rerender=""/>

   </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Minus all necessary error checking and other features considered best practice or possible logic problems.

Basically this creates a contact and uses the first an last name to create the associated account.