# How to concatenate a static value to a field?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, compile-error

I have a custom object (project) in that I've project name field(Text). Once I enter the project name, `"fita"` should be added to the end. For example, if I enter ABC for project name, then it should display as ABC FITA. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class insertname {
    public Project__c pro{get;set;} 
    public insertname(ApexPages.StandardController sc) { 
        pro = new Project__c(); 
    } 
    public pagereference save() { 
        Project__c p = new Project__c(); 
        p.Project_Name__c= Project_Name__c + ' ' + "fita"; 
        insert p; 
        return new pagereference('/'+ pro.id); 
    } 
}
```

My code fails to save with this error:

> Unrecognized symbol '"', which is not a valid Apex identifier

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try adding some code which you tried and tell us where you're stuck

Comment: There are numerous examples available. A simple Google search returned similar results:[VF page to insert contact and account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83259/visualforce-page-to-create-both-an-account-and-a-contact)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has been asked on numerous forums, including SFSE, and hundreds of examples are available. It seems that the OP did no research or work himself.

Comment: Hi chidambara, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to read [ask], scroll through the [tour], and visit the [help]. You will find that you get much better assistance from this community if you always include your error message ***verbatim***. If you had done so in this post, your question would have read as clearly asking why your code failed to compile, not a request to write your code for you. As it is, even after adding your code the question was still lacking this vital information.

Comment: okay, I am new to SFSE, going forward I will follow your instructions. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a look at compilation errors that you get. To be more precise, check this line:

```
p.Project_Name__c= Project_Name__c + ' ' + "fita";
```

You use double quotation marks, which normally lead to a compilation error. I just tried to save a class with this line of code in it:

```
String s = 'test' + "bla";
```

And I got the following errors:

> classes/testDoubleQuotes.cls: Unrecognized symbol '"', which is not a valid Apex identifier. (Line: 22, Column: 24)
>   classes/testDoubleQuotes.cls: Unrecognized symbol '"', which is not a valid Apex identifier. (Line: 22, Column: 28)
>   classes/testDoubleQuotes.cls: Variable does not exist: bla (Line: 22, Column: 25)

So change your double quotes to single quotes.

Also, your return statement doesn't really make sense. You instantiate a new variable `p`, use it and then return the id of `pro`, which will most likely be `null`. So your page would then redirect to **/null**